# Does VSS to TFS migration with VSSConverter preserves permissions?

Tags: tfs, permissions, migration, visual-sourcesafe, vssconverter

I have successfully converted from VSS to TFS 2008, using VSSConverter tool.

However, now in TFS users don't have permissions to read/edit the files they used to (in VSS).

I guessed that with a proper Users map.xml, the permissions would be preserved. But I have searched for this information and couldn't find it anywhere.

Could anyone confirm that the permissions are or are not migrated with VSSConverter tool?

Thank you,
Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSSConverter will not create the user accounts or migrate permissions to TFS. You have to provide the required permissions for users to TFS. The entries  in Usermap.xml file is used to assign destination users, it means the history will be transferred to the specified mapped users in TFS.

Comment: Ohh, ok, too bad, thought they did. Thanks!